# `stdin` and `stdout` handle

Tags: haskell, stdout, stdin, handle

I am testing a program. Specifically, I am testing a function in isolation. It requires a handle that can be both read and wrote. The problem is, `stdin` or `stdout` alone can't do the job. I don't want to rewrite my code just because of such a test, nor do I want to have to open up a socket just for a test either. Also, the program isn't usable yet (have the functions are undefined) so I can't just test it by running it.

What is a handle that gets it input from `stdin` and output from `stdout` in haskell.

Comment: Is it unreasonable to change your code to take two handles, one for input and one for output?

Comment: Well, it would be cleaner with out it I think. I guess I could do that though.

Comment: I tend to just pass handles around (for stdin/out/err) and point them to [`Data.Knob`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/knob-0.1.1/docs/Data-Knob.html) instances if I need “pure” testing.

Answer (score 18):

One simple way to do this is to use a `Pipe` to abstract out reads and writes to handles.  One type you can use is:

```
example :: Monad m => Pipe String String m ()
```

For example, let's say that your original code looked something like this:

```
original :: IO ()
original = do
    str1 <- getLine
    str2 <- getLine
    putStrLn (str1 ++ str2)
```

The new `pipes` version would look like this:

```
import Pipes

example :: Monad m => Pipe String String m ()
example = do
    str1 <- await
    str2 <- await
    yield (str1 ++ str2)
```

Then, you can test it purely like this:

```
>>> import qualified Pipes.Prelude as Pipes
>>> Pipes.toList (each ["Hello, ", "world!"] >-> example)
["Hello, world!"]
```

... or you can test it with real input and output:

```
>>> runEffect $ Pipes.stdinLn >-> example >-> Pipes.stdoutLn
Hello, <Enter>
world!<Enter>
Hello, world!
```

This lets you keep your main logic pure, and then choose whether or not to run it purely or impurely.